# How translate my application with string.xml files?

Tags: android, xml, string, android-activity, multilingual

I created this series of xml files

```
res/values/strings.xml     <--- The default language 'it'
res/values-en/strings.xml  <--- English
```

So in my string.xml there are some, and i repeat, some strings of my application in my language but not all. For example i have some textview like this

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Temperature);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Temperature: "+ "<small> <font color='#59c3fa'>" + temperature + "°C</font></small>"));
```

That there isn't in the string.xml file... Have i to add every textview? How it works? Can someone make an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the string from strings.xml, you have to use `getResources().getString(R.string./*String name in the xml*/)`

This will fetch the String from the appropriate `xml` file (`values-en` if locale of the phone is English) and if the String is not found in `values-en` (or the locale is not found), it fetches it from the `/res/values` folder

Just make sure you have all Strings mapped in both `strings.xml` files and do not hardcode the string (as you did with "Temprature:")

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Temperature: "+ "<small> <font color='#59c3fa'>" + temperature + "°C</font></small>"));
```

Instead use:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.temprature)+": "+ "<small> <font color='#59c3fa'>" + temperature + "°C</font></small>"));
```

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks i'll try later. But how can i test if it works? Is there a solution? Just to know..

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow. What do you need to test?

Comment: I mean, how can i know if it works? If it is all correct and who download my application for example in England see  the english language? Do you follow me now?

Comment: You can change the language of your test phone/Emulator to English, so you can see if it works properly

Comment: It depends on the phone locale not the phone location (if you have a phone with Italian language in England, it will display Italian language)

Comment: Ah ok thank you :) so if i change language in my phone it would displays the english language for example if all it's correct right?